# How do chained comparisons in Python actually work?

Tags: python, comparison-operators, python-internals

The [Python Doc for Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) says:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

And these SO questions/answers shed some more light on such usage:

- [Python comparison operators chaining/grouping left to right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753474/python-comparison-operators-chaining-grouping-left-to-right)
- [What does "evaluated only once" mean for chained comparisons in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664292/what-does-evaluated-only-once-mean-for-chained-comparisons-in-python), in particular [the currently-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664292/what-does-evaluated-only-once-mean-for-chained-comparisons-in-python/1664307#1664307)

So something like (contrived example):

```
if 1 < input("Value:") < 10: print "Is greater than 1 and less than 10"
```

only asks for input once. This makes sense. And this:

```
if 1 < input("Val1:") < 10 < input("Val2:") < 20: print "woo!"
```

only asks for `Val2` **if** `Val1` is between 1 & 10 and only prints "woo!" **if** `Val2` is also between 10 and 20 (proving they can be 'chained arbitrarily'). This also makes sense.

But I'm still curious how this is actually implemented/interpreted at the lexer/parser/compiler (or whatever) level.

Is the first example above basically implemented like this:

```
x = input("Value:")
1 < x and x < 10: print "Is between 1 and 10"
```

where `x` really only exists (and is actually essentially unnamed) for those comparisons? Or does it somehow make the comparison operator return both the boolean result and the evaluation of the right operand (to be used for further comparison) or something like that?

Extending analysis to the second example leads me to believe it's using something like an unnamed intermediate result (someone educate me if there's a term for that) as it doesn't evaluate all the operands before doing the comparison.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply let Python tell you what bytecode is produced with the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html):

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(): return 1 < input("Value:") < 10
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (input)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('Value:')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 DUP_TOP             
             13 ROT_THREE           
             14 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             17 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    27
             20 LOAD_CONST               3 (10)
             23 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             26 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   27 ROT_TWO             
             28 POP_TOP             
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

Python uses a stack; the [`CALL_FUNCTION` bytecode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION) uses items on the stack (the `input` global and the `'Value:'` string) to call a function with one argument, to replace those two items on the stack with the result of the function call. Before the function call, the the constant `1` was loaded on the stack.

So by the time `input` was called the stack looks like:

```
input_result
1
```

and [`DUP_TOP`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-DUP_TOP) duplicates the top value, before [rotating the top three stack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_THREE) values to arrive at:

```
1
input_result
input_result
```

and a `COMPARE_OP` to test the top two items with `<`, replacing the top two items with the result.

If that result was `False` the [`JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP` bytecode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP) jumps over to 27, which rotates the `False` on top with the remaining `input_result` to clear that out with a `POP_TOP`, to then return the remaining `False` top value as the result.

If the result `True` however, that value is popped of the stack by the `JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP` bytecode and in it's place the `10` value is loaded on top and we get:

```
10    
input_result
```

and another comparison is made and returned instead.

In summary, essentially Python then does this:

```
stack_1 = stack_2 = input('Value:')
if 1 < stack_1:
    result = False
else:
    result = stack_2 < 10
```

with the `stack_*` values cleared again.

The stack, then, holds the *unnamed intermediate result* to compare

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Didn't know about `dis`, which is pretty cool. Extending this to the second example shows it doing the same thing (which of course makes sense) - it leaves the previous result on the stack, gets the input onto the stack, and does the next comparison. Sweet!

Comment: I think you did ROT_THREE wrong. Should make the stack [input_result, 1, input_result]. I'd fix it but don't know how you'd like to correct the *"essentially Python then does this"* part.