# Python shorthand for multiple conditionals in an if statement

Tags: python

```
if x == y != z:
    print (x + y)
```

Is this shorthand for if x == y and y != z? It works in my code, but I'm unsure how multiple conditionals are interpreted when they are not all == or !=, or otherwise written out in the latter form above.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754726/how-do-chained-comparisons-in-python-actually-work which shows how chained comparisons work at the bytecode level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes as is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> (...)
>
> Comparisons can be **chained arbitrarily**, e.g., **`x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`**, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

So you can chain any kind of comparator: `<`, `>`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`, `<>`, `!=`, `is [not]`, and `[not] in`.

The documentation further makes it more formal:

> Formally, if *a*, *b*, *c*, ..., *y*, *z* are expressions and *op1*, *op2*, ..., *opN* are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

So for instance:

```
'a' in 'ab' in 'zabc'
```

is equivalent to:

```
'a' in 'ab' and 'ab' in 'zabc'
```

Comment: Nice work. We can use this as a dupe target for future questions.