# Certain conditions evaluate differently then expected in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, operators, boolean-expression

Currently creating a piece that takes values a given value in an array and adds 32

My IDE (PyCharm) recommended that I remove a redundancy in my code by doing the following

```
if ascii_key[i] >= 65 and ascii_key[i] <= 90:
    ascii_key[i] = ascii_key[i] + 32
```

to

```
if 65 <= ascii_key[i] <= 90:
    ascii_key[i] = ascii_key[i] + 32
```

Both solutions work for me, but I'm curious as to why this arrangement of conditions breaks

```
if ascii_key[i] <= 65 >= 90:
    ascii_key[i] = ascii_key[i] + 32
```

I'd appreciate an explanation in pseudo-code if convenient, I'm still a bit novice

Comment: because it tests if 65 is greater equal 95 ...

Comment: `a < b < c` is just shorthand notation for `(a < b) and (b < c)`. Writing `ascii_key[i] <= 65 >= 90` is the same as `(ascii_key[i] <= 65) and (65 >= 90)`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: See [chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

Comment: [How do chained comparisons in Python actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28754726/1324033)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the third code provided by you.

`ascii_key[i] <= 65 >= 90` this is always evaluated to `False`.

`ascii_key[i] <= 65 >= 90` is evaluated as `ascii_key[i] <= 65 and 65 >= 90`. `65>=90` is `False`.

Byte-code evaluation of `a<b<c`.

```
In [17]: dis.dis('a<b<c')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
             12 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             14 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

Byte-code evaluation of `a<b and b<c`.

```
In [18]: dis.dis('a<b and b<c')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
              6 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    14
              8 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             10 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             12 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can observe observe `a<b<c` is equivalent to `a<b and b<c`.

Answer (score 0):

it is due to how the conditions are resolved.
`if ascii_key[i] >= 65 and ascii_key[i] <= 90` and `if 65 <= ascii_key[i] <= 90` are equivalent.
While `if ascii_key[i] <= 65 >= 90` gets resolved to this: `if ascii_key[i] <= 65 and 65 >= 90`
65 >= 90 is never true.

First the condition `65 <= ascii_key[i]` and then the other condition `ascii_key[i] <= 90` are evaluated and chained with an AND.

Cheers