# SQLAlchemy and chained comparison: TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I tried to make the following query as a Pythonic chained comparison for filtering a range of inequalities:

```py
minSalary = 0
maxSalary = 4000
results = Employee.query.filter(minSalary <= Employee.salary <= maxSalary).all()
```

But I got this error:

```py
TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching around to no avail but got inspired by this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681231/sqlalchemy-unexpected-results-when-using-and-and-or). I wanted to leave an answer or comment on said question, but thought this should be a separate question and answer instead.

Basically I thought that Pythonic compound statements are supported by SQLAlchemy (i.e. a

```py
results = Employee.query.filter(minSalary <= Employee.salary).filter(Employee.salary <= maxSalary).all()
```

Comment: SQLA cannot support that comparison, because it is transformed to `minSalary <= Employee.salary and Employee.salary <= maxSalary` behind the scenes by Python. The SQL way of doing that would be `Employee.salary.between(minSalary, maxSalary)`.

Comment: Here's the detailed explanation of what goes on with chained comparisons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754726/how-do-chained-comparisons-in-python-actually-work.