# Chaining comparison operators in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

The following expression yields the boolean value `True` using pure Python:

```
6 > 5 > 4
```

What is the most pythonic way of chaining comparison operators in a Pandas DataFrame similar to the above?

Desired output here is a new column `greater` as per example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[6,5,4],[1,2,3],index=["a"],columns=["foo","bar","baz"])
```

Comparing two columns works as expected:

```
df.loc[df.foo > df.bar, "greater"] = "yes"


foo bar baz greater
a   6   5   4   yes
b   1   2   3   NaN
```

If we try chaining three cols as per the pure Python example:

```
df.loc[df.foo > df.bar > df.baz, "greater"] = "yes"
```

This returns the following error.  My understanding is we are trying to compare the bool output from first check with an int in col `baz`

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I can use the following expression but is there a cleaner way similar to the pure Python example?

```
df.loc[(df.foo > df.bar) & (df.bar > df.baz), "greater"] = "yes"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In boolean indexing with `loc` not possible, here is trick with [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), limitation is unique index values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[6,5,4],[1,2,3]],columns=["foo","bar","baz"])
                   
df.loc[df.query('foo > bar > baz').index , "greater"] = "yes"            
print (df)
   foo  bar  baz greater
0    6    5    4     yes
1    1    2    3     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible, as you have vectors, you need to split the operation in two:

```
df.loc[(df.foo > df.bar) & (df.bar > df.baz), "greater"] = "yes"
```

Why?
`a > b > c` in pure python is an [optimization at the bytecode level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754726/how-do-chained-comparisons-in-python-actually-work), which is not possible with arrays as for some values the shortcut might happen, while for others it won't

The pandas equivalent IMO would be `between`:

```
df.loc[df['bar'].between(df['baz'], df['foo'], inclusive='neither'), 'greater'] = 'yes'
```