# Chained comparisons not always executing functional calls (side-effects)

Tags: python, comparison-operators, side-effects

I was testing out comparison chaining and I noticed that in certain patterns the some of the function calls are not executed.

If I plan on using the function calls to do things what would be the best way to ensure that they are executed while still being concise? (is this considered a bad practice)

```
def foo(bar):
    print(f"\tbar")
    return bar

a = b = False 

print (f"one = {foo(a)==foo(b)==True}")
print (f"two = {True==foo(a)==foo(b)}")
print (f"three = {foo(a)==True==foo(b)}")

a = True

print (f"one = {foo(a)==foo(b)==True}")
print (f"two = {True==foo(a)==foo(b)}")
print (f"three = {foo(a)==True==foo(b)}")

a = b = True

print (f"one = {foo(a)==foo(b)==True}")
print (f"two = {True==foo(a)==foo(b)}")
print (f"three = {foo(a)==True==foo(b)}")
```

Output:

```
    bar
    bar
one = False
    bar   < only executes once
two = False
    bar   < only executes once
three = False
    bar
    bar
one = False
    bar
    bar
two = False
    bar
    bar
three = False
    bar
    bar
one = True
    bar
    bar
two = True
    bar
    bar
three = True
```

note: reviewing the suggested questions I saw [how-do-chained-comparisons-in-python-actually-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754726/how-do-chained-comparisons-in-python-actually-work)

> ...
> In summary, essentially Python then does this:

```
stack_1 = stack_2 = input('Value:')
if 1 < stack_1:
    result = False
else:
    result = stack_2 < 10
```

> with the stack_* values cleared again.
>
> The stack, then, holds the unnamed intermediate result to compare [martijn-pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)

Comment: Chaining combines the comparisons with `and` and `and` performs short-circuiting.

Comment: To contextualize things a bit more, `foo(a)==foo(b)==foo(c)` is evaluated exactly as `temp == foo(c) if foo(a) == (temp := foo(b)) else False`